# How to get a list of antonyms lemmas using Python, NLTK and WordNet?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I would like to generate a list of antonyms lemmas of a given lemma using Python, NLTK, and WordNet. In fact I just want to share a small utility function.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192979/how-to-generate-a-list-of-antonyms-for-adjectives-in-wordnet-using-python

Answer (score 4):

A simple Python and NLTK function that returns a list of antonyms

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def get_antonyms(input_lemma):
    antonyms = []
    for syn in wn.synsets(input_lemma):
        for lemma in syn.lemmas():
            if lemma.antonyms():
                antonyms.append(lemma.antonyms()[0].name())
    return antonyms
```

Related works: [How to generate a list of antonyms for adjectives in WordNet using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192979/how-to-generate-a-list-of-antonyms-for-adjectives-in-wordnet-using-python) and http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-synonymsantonyms-nltk-wordnet-python/

Comment: This is very similar to the code sample in http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-synonymsantonyms-nltk-wordnet-python/

Comment: Yes, you're right... I can cite this source, no problem. How can I do it?