# Finding the Antonym of a Word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

I'm working on an aspect-based sentiment analysis model using spaCy. I managed to extract aspects and adjectives as pairs in a list. I also included "not" before any adjective to handle any negations. I want to swap the adjective with its antonym if there is "not" before the adjective. I know spaCy has some similarity detection tools but I couldn't find anything about antonyms. Is it possible to do this with spaCy? If not how can I do it or is there a better way to handle the negations?

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

txt = "The performance of the product is not great but The price is fair."
txt = txt.lower()

output = []
doc = nlp(txt)

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)
matcher.add("mood",None,[{"LOWER":{"IN":["is","are"]}},{"LOWER":{"IN":["no","not"]},"OP":"?"},{"DEP":"advmod","OP":"?"},{"DEP":"acomp"}])
for nc in doc.noun_chunks:
    d = doc[nc.root.right_edge.i+1:nc.root.right_edge.i+1+3]
    matches = matcher(d)
    if matches:
        _, start, end = matches[0]
        output.append((nc.text, d[start+1:end].text))
    
print(output)
```

Expected output:

```
[('the performance', 'not great'), ('the product', 'not great'), ('the price', 'fair')]
```

Comment: Perhaps some of the many thesaurus sites night have an API you could call?  Interesting problem though, because a common antonym for "great" would be "small."  Not really applicable in context (e.g. "the performance was small")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task seems to best addressed with [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) to provide you the antonym. You can then potentially use either WordNet or some spellchecking library to list synonyms and find antonyms for these (they are likely to be not *exact* antonyms then). Good python libraries for this are: [pyenchant](http://pyenchant.github.io) or [hunspell](https://pypi.org/project/hunspell/).

WordNet (using API provided by NLTK - an 'older sister' NLP library to spaCy): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64320638/6573902) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441518/how-to-get-a-list-of-antonyms-lemmas-using-python-nltk-and-wordnet).