# Is there a way to find the antonym(word with the opposite meaning) of a word with python? Do you know a dataset or an nlp toolkit?

Tags: python, nlp, dataset

```
right-wing extremism -> left-wing extremism
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO ,see how do I ask a good question [ask], take our [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLTK is the main library for NLP and it includes many corpora. See the code here: [How to generate a list of antonyms for adjectives in WordNet using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192979/how-to-generate-a-list-of-antonyms-for-adjectives-in-wordnet-using-python)

NLTK documentation on using WordNet: https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html

Comment: So shouldn't you be flagging this as a duplicate?

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow to be honest

Answer (score 0):

The SPECIALIST Lexicon distributed by NLM, NIH has a wide coverage of 9K antonym pairs. You may check URL at:  https://lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/LSG/Projects/lexicon/current/web/index.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35561877)